# How to get random bounding boxes from image? (python)

Tags: python, image, bounding-box

I have a batch of images and I open each one using the open function with mode 'rb' and then I read each one using read function. Now I want to get 50 random bounding boxes from each image and read each bounding box again with open and read functions. Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Your question is confusing.

Comment: I want to take 50 random parts from an image. These parts will be the bounding boxes. Should I store them in different .jpg files and then read them using open and read functions? Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
from random import randint
from PIL import Image


def random_bbox(bbox):
    v = [randint(0, v) for v in bbox]
    left = min(v[0], v[2])
    upper = min(v[1], v[3])
    right = max(v[0], v[2])
    lower = max(v[1], v[3])
    return [left, upper, right, lower]

filename = "your_image.png"
im = Image.open(filename)
bbox = im.getbbox()
N = 50

for i in range(N):
    random_tile = im.crop(random_bbox(bbox))
    #random_tile.show()
```

As you can see, this solution is cropping random subimages from one image, as you can see I've commented the line `random_tile.show()`, now it's up to you how processing that random_tile (saving, tweaking, ...)

Comment: Thank you. I've already found solution with tensorflow. I am searching now how to save the bounding boxes in binary form as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn's [extract_patches_2d](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html) does just what you want.